# How to exit a while loop (continue)

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while, continue

I have been trying to fix a simple issue with my coding (I am new at C++).

Basically I am trying to exit a while loop using

`continue`

or

```
break
```

but it doesn't work. The issue is that the

```
cout << "it worked!";
```

part doesn't get executed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int userChoice=0;
    cout<<"1 for addiction and 2 for subtraction\n";
    do{
        if(cin >> userChoice){
            switch (userChoice) {
                case 1:
                    continue;
                case 2:
                    continue;
                default:
                    cout<<"Please select 1 for addiction or 2 for subtraction.\n";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }while(userChoice!=1 || userChoice!=2);

    cout<<"it worked!";
}

int addiction(int a,int b){
    return a+b;
}

int subtraction(int a,int b){
    return a-b;
}
```

Comment: Do you want `break` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 even with break that line doesn't get executed. in my Xcode it says: "Code will never be executed."

Comment: `userChoice!=1 || userChoice!=2` is always `true`, you mean `userChoice!=1 && userChoice!=2`.

Comment: @Jarod42 oof i just realized that right now. it all makes sense now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to leave your loop, because whatever `userChoice` is it is *always* either "not 1" or "not 2" (it can never be both!).

So since the `continue` will just always go to another iteration, and since the `break` jumps you out of the `switch` (not the loop), your loop can never end and the `cout` will never be executed.

It seems to me that you want to iterate for only as long as `userChoice` is not 1 *and* it's also not 2:

```
while(userChoice!=1 && userChoice!=2);
```

This is sometimes confusing to beginners who take English shortcuts like "userChoice is not 1 or 2" when they really mean "userChoice is neither 1 nor 2" and don't realise that C++ doesn't have a "neither/nor" construct at all so end up writing "userChoice is not 1 or userChoice is not 2" by mistake without thinking it through.

Since positives are more intuitive than negatives, one way to clarify it to yourself is to apply De Morgan's law; your fixed code is equivalent to:

```
while(!(userChoice == 1 || userChoice == 2));
```

i.e. "loop while it's *not* the case that userChoice is either 1 or 2". It's arguably worse code, but it can help your understanding to briefly write it out that way.